# How we can get the current block author account id in POA solochain?

Tags: pallet, solo-chain, poa

I am working on a solochain I want to pass the account of the block author in a pallet config in runtime of the chain. How can i get the the account is of the current block author?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`pallet-authorsip`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/frame/authorship) and its configuration in different live runtimes if you need examples.

This pallet provides what you are looking for.